# What are my options to implement an authentication/log in service for my WP7 application?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, windows-phone-7

I am developing a project in WP7 Silverlight.
My project includes a Clientapplication, a WCF-service for communication to my business layer and a EF database.

I want the users to provide a userspecific username and password to access my application. How can i do this? 
Is there anyway to use Membership provider like we do in asp.net?

It would be good if i could implement different roles aswell, like if the user is a normal user or administrator etcetera.

What are my options to implement this kind of solution for my WP7 Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create this behaviour, you'd create a form in your app which captures the users credentials (username and password) you'd then pass them over an SSL connection (you'd never send them in plain text over an unencrypted/unsecured connection I'm sure) to a suitably created function in your WCF service. Your service will then validate the credentials and return either a failure message or a success message and details of which role the user has/is.

Managing roles, etc. is something that you'd configure on the back end.

It's the same way you'd do things if you were creating a log in form on a website and the WCF service was on a different domain or server.

There is no default login control for WP7. You'll have to create your own, but as this is just a couple of textboxes, labels and a[n appbar]button, that shouldn't cause you too much work.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for trying to explain. I think i'm clear about a solution now. I found a blog on the internet, would you say this would help me in my situation? [blog](http://www.kotancode.com/2010/08/06/aspnet-authentication-wp7/)